# NameError on initialization of class instance

Tags: python

I have been playing around with scripts for a couple of weeks and have not had any issues, but I am now trying to create a class and am running into problems.

I don't fully understand it myself but I am getting this error `NameError: global name 'instance_status_check' is not defined` when I try to create an instance of the following class.

I am fully aware the class isn't doing much at this time but I can't move on until I resolve the problem. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
import sys
import boto  
import boto.ec2 

class Monitor:

    def __init__(self,conn,identifier):
        self.connection = conn
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.dispatcher ={'1': instance_status_check}

    def user_menu():
        for i, value in self.dispatcher.itertems():
            print "Please press {i} for {value}".format(i,value)

    def instance_status_check():
        pass
```

Comment: What are you assigning as a value to that `dispatcher` dictionary?

Comment: I am going to use it to build up a user menu - ie calling dispatcher['1']() to call the instance_status_check function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `self` parameter from both methods and it is `iteritems` not `itertems`:

```
class Monitor:  # upper case for class names
    def __init__(self,conn,identifier):
        self.connection = conn
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.dispatcher ={'1': self.instance_status_check} # call self.instance_status_check()

    def user_menu(self): # self here
        for i, value in self.dispatcher.iteritems():
            print("Please press {i} for {value}".format(i,value))

    def instance_status_check(self): # self here
        return "In status method"

m = Monitor(3,4)
print(m.dispatcher["1"]())
In status method
```

I suggest you have a look at the classes tutorial from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: That works but was not what I was hoping to do with the dictionary value, I was hoping to build up a user menu and call for example dispatcher['1']() to call the instance_status_check function

Comment: I edited to  remove the parens, you should look at class methods if you want to share the dict among instances of the class

Comment: Thanks that works, can you explain why I need self. before a call to a function? Thanks

Comment: `self` is used by convention, it can technically be anything but I would stick with self, it refers to the instance that the method is called on. There is more info in the link I posted, it covers a lot of the basics

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because you have defined `instance_status_check` after you are already using it.

Move the declaration above the class:

```
def instance_status_check():
    pass 

class monitor:

    def __init__(self,conn,identifier):
        self.connection = conn
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.dispatcher ={'1': instance_status_check}

    def user_menu(self):
        for i, value in self.dispatcher.itertems():
            print "Please press {i} for {value}".format(i,value)
```

Also, this will not print `Please press 1 for instance_status_check` it will print something like `Please press 1 for <function instance_status_check at 0xsomething>`

Comment: So in normal circumstances, what I was doing would not be a problem? For example there was a different value for the dictionary entry? Thanks